# How do you show the fields of some nodes on Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j for the first time. When I am querying nodes, it would only show their name. Would it be possible to show multiple fields beside a name, like age, location, etc..?

Comment: I assume you are querying on the neo4j browser, It's not possible for now to show multiple fields. You can show any one of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the neo4j Browser, the default `Graph` tab (in the light-gray vertical panel to the left of the visualization) only supports showing a single value for a node at a time (since there is not much room to display such data when a lot of nodes and relationships are displayed).

But you can see node (and relationship) properties by clicking on the `Table` or `Text` tab.